# Receber informação do banco de dados e enviar para o campo do formulario

Tags: php, html5

Bom dia. Queria saber como faço para que a informação que eu quero  seja enviada para dentro do **input**(Nome Cliente), pois fiz o select e a informação não era colocada no campo do formulário, ficava em cima . Segue meu código abaixo.

**PHP**

```
<body>

        <?php
        include_once '../DAO/Connect.php';
        include_once '../model/Cliente.php';

        $conexao = new Conexao();
        $cliente = new Cliente();
        $cliente = $conexao->selectCliente("_ID=" . '10');

        $cliente->getNome();
        echo $cliente->getNome(); ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="get">  
            <label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="nome" size="80" /><br  />

            <label>Nome Fantasia</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="nome-fantasia" size="80"  /><br />

            <div class="ao-lado">
                <label>CNPJ/CPF</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="cpf" size="37" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Onde queres colocar o nome? no value do input? Esse código PHP e HTML estão no mesmo ficheiro PHP?

Comment: Testa `<input type="text" name="nome" size="80" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNome(); ?>" />`

Comment: Opa , desculpa a demora, tinha dado uma saída. Mas ja voltei

Comment: Estão todos no mesmo ficheiro, sim, quero colocar no value do input

Comment: Amigo, deu certo. Muito Obrigado! Se quiser colocar como resposta, eu marcarei como certa .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir o valor da variável dentro do HTML podes concatenar no caso de estares a fazer `echo` do HTML, ou no teu caso usar `echo` de PHP dentro do HTML:

```
<label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
<input type="text" name="nome" size="80" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNome(); ?>" /><br  />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta !

Answer (score 2):

Você deve dar um echo no atributo `value` do seu `input` com chamando o dado desejado.

***Script*** de exemplo:

```
<form action="#" method="get">  
    <label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome" size="80" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNome(); ?>" /><br  />

    <label>Nome Fantasia</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome-fantasia" size="80" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNomeFantasia(); ?>" /><br />

    <div class="ao-lado">
        <label>CNPJ/CPF</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="cpf" size="37" value="<?php echo $cliente->getCpf(); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!